# Use apt-get/yum without sudo

Tags: python, linux

I built a Python script which install some framework. This framework depends on some packages, one of them is libguestfs. Everything works fine with sudo, but I was requested to run this installer script without the sudo.

What are my options?

Regards,
Ivgi

Comment: Is the problem that `sudo` isn't available on the target machine or that they don't want to enter a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some commands require higher privileges. If your problem is the input of the password, then try setting up automatic sudoers, so when you use "sudo apt-get foo" you don't have to input the password.

Please, take a look at

> > http://jeromejaglale.com/doc/unix/ubuntu_sudo_without_password

for information on setting up automatic sudoers..

You might also want to check out how to limit sudo privileges, so the user with automatic sudoing can't escalate to root, etc. It's basically not good if he can sudo everything, the sudoed programs should be whitelisted. I'm not going to go into this for the sake of security, but escalation from sudoer to root can be done in less than 2 seconds, if he has unrestricted sudo access.

TL;DR check out for example [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/767415/limit-user-to-execute-selective-commands-linux) or just google `limiting sudo commands` or `restrict sudo access`..

Comment: thanks for the heads up, I'll update it when I'm on my computer..

Comment: Yay, finally updated!